# Tensorflow reading data from AWS s3 bucket

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-s3

I want to stream my data files from an AWS s3 bucket. I'm following the setup described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/docs/deploy/s3.md), but using tensorflow 2.

The setup specifies that you can use a AWS configuration file in `~/.aws/credentials`, but I also tried using the environment variables. However the smoke test below keeps giving the following error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: File system scheme 's3' not implemented`.

```py
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
print(file_io.stat('s3://bucketname/key/'))
```

Comment: I did not manage to solve it, but also went to download the data because its just much much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself back at my question a few times. Generallly, when you experience this, you are trying to communicate with S3 on Windows in a place it is only implemented on linux.

My main advice is to not do when it comes to training data. **If possible, try to download the files because it will be worth the overhead**. Especially when using tools like sagemaker, which have very convenient methods for downloading the data at start-up. If you are really in need for quick startup & fast reading, it is worth looking at [FSx for Lustre](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/08/amazon-sagemaker-works-with-amazon-fsx-lustre-amazon-efs-model-training/).

A few times I used `smart_open` which works well on Windows and linux.

```
from smart_open import open
with open("s3://bucket/key) as f:
   ...
```

Comment: I'm using linux on EC2 instance and still unable to access S3 using tf.data.TFRecordDataset in which it outputs same error as your question.

Comment: Sad it still causes issues. My advice remains to either download the files (for example with sagemaker training jobs) or using FSx for Lustre if you need the data many times :)